# How can i track the structure of a table changes?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to track the table modification. How can i track? If the structure of a table changes (column name or column type or delete,insert colum) then i want to save to Logtable.
It's possible? What are the options?
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with [system trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B)
[image]